# ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock not working in chrome

Tags: javascript, c#, web

i have some code that work in ie but not in chrome and ff.

```
ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "Msg", "<script language='javascr`ipt'>NavigateSlip('SlipArea.aspx','link2');</script>", true);
```

any idea why?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you provide the `<script>` tags, then use false:

`ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "Msg", "<script language='javascript'>NavigateSlip('SlipArea.aspx','link2');</script>", false);`

Comment: hey, it didnt help to me :(

Comment: I've just created a small example here and it works as expected,  given that the functiuon `NavigateSlip()` is already provided in markup.